# UPDATE table with LEFT JOIN result

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-update

I need some help with one query in MySQL, here's the situation:

I have 2 tables, "phrases" and "authors" which I need to insert the amount of phrases each author have on phrases_qt field, with this query, I get the amount of phrases from each one:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT( p.author_id ) 
FROM authors a
LEFT JOIN phrases p ON a.id = p.author_id
GROUP BY a.name, p.author_id
```

which gave me this result:

```
+-------------------+------------------+
|name               |COUNT(p.author_id)|
+-------------------+------------------+
|Albert Einstein    |12                |
|Bill Gates         |10                |
+-------------------+------------------+
```

so how can I make a query to update "phrases_qt" fields from each author to the COUNT result?

EDIT == (show create tables)

show create table authors

```
CREATE TABLE `authors` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Author id',
 `thumbnail` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Author thumbnail image',
 `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Author name',
 `history` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Author history',
 `phrases_qt` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `id_2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

show create tables phrases

```
CREATE TABLE `phrases` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Phrase ID',
 `text` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'The phrase',
 `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Author ID',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `phrase` (`text`),
 KEY `author_id` (`author_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `phrases_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `authors` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the final result would look like in `phrases`? What it sounds like is that you're updating the same `COUNT()` value for every row of `phrases` per author id.

Comment: In other words, if `phrases` has a one-to-many relationship on a FK to `authors` (which is what it sounds like), the same count would appear for every row. The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table would help if posted above.

Comment: I edited the post with show create table's result, thank you guys for your attention PS; idnore id_2 KEY, it must be from some test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it but this should work:

```
UPDATE authors PA 
INNER JOIN (SELECT p.author_id, COUNT( p.author_id ) AS AuthorCount
FROM phrases p
GROUP BY p.author_id) tblA
ON tblA.author_id = PA.id
SET phrases_qt = AuthorCount
```

Comment: That is not valid syntax for MySQL

Comment: MySQL `UPDATE` syntax has no `FROM` clause.

Comment: That looks almost right but you shouldn't need the join inside the subquery.It can be done using only `phrases` in the subquery.

Comment: Here you can work with this. I had started it but you're far enough along to work it out. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/396d2

Comment: But, even if this was from mysql, aren't you updating the "phrases" table? actually i want to update "authors" table "phrases_qt" field with the amount of phrases the author have on "phrases" table, sorry if this sounds a little confusing '-'

Comment: Look at the updated query. I changed it to update author table. Thanks @MichaelBerkowski for the help... I started it assuming its MSSQL.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i didn't saw that you have updated, but, this query is giving me syntax error near 'phrases p GROUP BY p.author_id) tblA ON tlbA.author_id = PA.id SET phrases_qt = ', this is the current ctrl+c: UPDATE authors PA INNER JOIN 
(SELECT p.author_id, COUNT( p.author_id ) AS AuthorCount phrases p GROUP BY p.author_id) tblA ON tlbA.author_id = PA.id SET phrases_qt = AuthorCount